# Having trouble deploying Streamset Data Collector on Azure

Tags: azure, streamsets

I'm am attempting to deploy the Streamset Data Collector for Azure on Azure (obviously!) and it consistently fails with a rather mysterious OSProvisioningInternalError after the VM has been provisioned. Everything is deployed but it looks like the VM itself may not be in the csorrect state. Has anyone seen this or been able to solve for it?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Where are you seeing the OSProvisioning error? Can you view the step in Deployments as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations ? If so please update your question with details of the error.  Since this is a Marketplace resource, there may be no way to fix it, it depends on what the details are.  Did you choose an appropriately sized VM? It requires 2 CPU cores and 1GB RAM so so B2s or up would suffice.  (A-series VMs shouldn't be used in production)

Comment: Jamie thanks - my latest deployment actually worked and I suspect it's an issue with the user I was given to configure. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hi @OrangeSocks - could you copy that comment to the answer so people can see that the problem was solved? Thanks!